# Why do I get the constructor BigDecimal(Number) is undefined?

Tags: java, numbers, jasper-reports, classcastexception, bigdecimal

I have made a variable in Jasper Reports with a Value Class Name of `java.math.BigDecimal`. I set the expression as:

```
new BigDecimal(PRODUCT($F{CurrentValue},100)).divide($V{current_val_total})
```

but I keep getting the error:

```
The constructor BigDecimal(Number) is undefined
```

and

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
1. The constructor BigDecimal(Number) is undefined
            value = new BigDecimal(PRODUCT (((java.math.BigDecimal)field_CurrentValue.getValue()),100)).divide(((java.math.BigDecimal)variable_current_val_total.getValue())); //$JR_EXPR_ID=18$
                    <--------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
2. The constructor BigDecimal(Number) is undefined
            value = new BigDecimal(PRODUCT (((java.math.BigDecimal)field_CurrentValue.getOldValue()),100)).divide(((java.math.BigDecimal)variable_current_val_total.getOldValue())); //$JR_EXPR_ID=18$
                    <------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
3. The constructor BigDecimal(Number) is undefined
            value = new BigDecimal(PRODUCT (((java.math.BigDecimal)field_CurrentValue.getValue()),100)).divide(((java.math.BigDecimal)variable_current_val_total.getEstimatedValue())); //$JR_EXPR_ID=18$
                    <--------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
3 errors
.
at   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:215)
at net.sf.jasperreports.eclipse.builder.JasperReportCompiler.compileReport(JasperReportCompiler.java:195)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler.compileJasperDesign(ReportControler.java:439)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler.access$15(ReportControler.java:416)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler$5.run(ReportControler.java:341)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: I suggest you use a method which exists or create one to do this conversion.

Comment: You can probably call `toString()` on the `Number` you get from `PRODUCT`.

Answer (score 3):

`PRODUCT` returns a [`java.lang.Number`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) see [Jasper Reports Functions](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/functions/FunctionsReport.html).

There is **no constructor** in [`java.math.BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) that takes `java.lang.Number`.

You need to use one of the constructors available in api, I would suggest `BigDecimal(double val)`, hence calling the `doubleValue()` function on `java.lang.Number`

```
new BigDecimal(PRODUCT($F{CurrentValue},100).doubleValue()).divide($V{current_val_total})
```

or to use the `String` value of `Number`

```
new BigDecimal(PRODUCT($F{CurrentValue},100).toString()).divide($V{current_val_total})
```

Which one is "best" to use depends on the actual class of `Number`, see [Convert Java Number to BigDecimal : best way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216248/convert-java-number-to-bigdecimal-best-way) for more information. However in report generation with normal rounding it will not make much difference.