# BigDecimal/double Precision - number rounds up higher

Tags: java, precision, bigdecimal

The second of below method calls, to setYCoordinate(), gets incorrect value -89.99999435599995 instead of -89.99999435599994.

The first call to setXCoordinate() gets correct value 29.99993874900002.

```
setXCoordinate(BigDecimal.valueOf(29.99993874900002))
setYCoordinate(BigDecimal.valueOf(-89.99999435599994))
```

I put a breakpoint inside BigDecimal.valueOf() - this method's code looks as below -

```
public static BigDecimal valueOf(double val) {
        // Reminder: a zero double returns '0.0', so we cannot fastpath
        // to use the constant ZERO.  This might be important enough to
        // justify a factory approach, a cache, or a few private
        // constants, later.
        return new BigDecimal(Double.toString(val));
    }
```

The argument received by valueOf i.e. "double val" itself is -89.99999435599995 when inspected. Why? I have Java version set as below in my Maven pom.xml

```
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
```

Comment: Java has apparently [15 decimal digits of precision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36345535/1270789), but your coordinates have 16 digits. You shouldn't be relying on that degree of accuracy anyway.

Comment: @KenY-N That's not what it says in your citation. It has 15.9 *integral* decimal digits of precision. What that translates to after the decimal point is value-dependent. See the last sentence of your citation. Which I wrote.

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216248/convert-java-number-to-bigdecimal-best-way

Comment: ...but the conversion that causes the confusion in this question happens *before* any method is invoked, when the literal is interpreted as `double`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because a `double` can't retain that much precision; you shouldn't use a `double`, but rather a `String` when initializing your `BigDecimal`:

```
new BigDecimal("29.99993874900002");
new BigDecimal("-89.99999435599994");
```

See: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken/588029)

Comment: After changing to setYCoordinate(new BigDecimal(-89.99999435599994)) the value received by setYCoordinate is -89.99999435599994512813282199203968048095703125 - I do not need and want that many digits as I am doing an exact comparison elsewhere.

Comment: @jerry.pepper You should use a `String` as shown in my answer.

Comment: @jerry.pepper you can either round the result is use the String representation to get more precision than double supports.

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion has nothing to do with `BigDecimal`.

```
double d = -89.99999435599994;
System.out.println(d); //or inspecting it in a debugger
```

yields:

> -89.99999435599995

This is just the way `doubles` work in java, in combination with the way [`Double.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double)) defines the `String`-representation. This conversion happens before any method is invoked, when the literal is interpreted as `double`. The details are specified in [JLS Chapter 3.10.2. Floating-Point Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2) and the [JavaDocs of `Double.valueOf(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)).

---

If you need to express the value `-89.99999435599994` as `BigDecimal`, the easiest way is to use the [constructor taking a String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)), as other answers have already pointed out:

BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("-89.99999435599994");

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("-89.99999435599994");
System.out.println(bd);
```

yields:

> -89.99999435599994

Answer (score 0):

You're right on the edge of precision for a double-precision floating point value, with 16 digits specified, and there's just shy of a full 16 digits of decimal accuracy available. If you skip BigDecimal entirely, just set a double to -89.99999435599994 and print it back out, you'll get -89.99999435599995.