# Incorrect calculations with BigDecimal numbers in Java

Tags: java

I'm writing a method that counts Fermat Point for my homework. But i can not pass the tests.
I already tried to do all calculations in simple double. But it is working the same way.
Two tests failed, and I think it's not about rounding.
[image]
[image]

Problems are with 'y' counting and the strangest thing that in one test it not enought numbers, and in other it seems that can be rounded.
What am i doing wrong?

```
    BigDecimal ax = new BigDecimal(points.get(0).getX());
    BigDecimal ay = new BigDecimal(points.get(0).getY());
    BigDecimal bx = new BigDecimal(points.get(1).getX());
    BigDecimal by = new BigDecimal(points.get(1).getY());
    BigDecimal cx = new BigDecimal(points.get(2).getX());
    BigDecimal cy = new BigDecimal(points.get(2).getY());


    BigDecimal firstX = cx.add(bx).add(cy.subtract(by).multiply(new BigDecimal(StrictMath.sqrt(3))))
            .divide(new BigDecimal(2.0d), 20, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

    BigDecimal firstY = cy.add(by).add(bx.subtract(cx).multiply(new BigDecimal(StrictMath.sqrt(3))))
            .divide(new BigDecimal(2.0d), 20, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);


    BigDecimal secondX = ax.add(bx).add(ay.subtract(by).multiply(new BigDecimal(StrictMath.sqrt(3))))
            .divide(new BigDecimal(2.0d), 20, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

    BigDecimal secondY = ay.add(by).add(bx.subtract(ax).multiply(new BigDecimal(StrictMath.sqrt(3))))
            .divide(new BigDecimal(2.0d), 20, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);


    BigDecimal a1 = cy.subtract(secondY);

    BigDecimal b1 = secondX.subtract(cx);

    BigDecimal a2 = ay.subtract(firstY);

    BigDecimal b2 = firstX.subtract(ax);


    BigDecimal d = a1.multiply(b2).subtract(a2.multiply(b1));


    BigDecimal c1 = secondY.multiply(cx).subtract(secondX.multiply(cy));

    BigDecimal c2 = firstY.multiply(ax).subtract(firstX.multiply(ay));


    BigDecimal resultX = b1.multiply(c2).subtract(b2.multiply(c1));
    resultX = resultX.divide(d, 16, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

    BigDecimal resultY = a2.multiply(c1).subtract(a1.multiply(c2));
    resultY = resultY.divide(d, 17, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Comment: This honestly reflects a problem with the tests, most likely; it shouldn't care about that level of accuracy in the doubles.  Otherwise -- as you're finding -- the calculations must be done in one exact way, and even mathematically equivalent alternatives don't work.

Comment: How did you get the reference values? You're using at least one problematic `double` calculation (`sqrt(3)`) which will introduce imprecise values. At the end of the day if your inputs are `double` then `BigDecimal` can't magically make all rounding and representation problems go away. They might just avoid adding further ones in the intermediate step, but won't remove existing problems.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BigDecimal/double Precision - number rounds up higher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51371109/bigdecimal-double-precision-number-rounds-up-higher)

Comment: Yes, thank you all!